# Symbols in swift - xcode 6

Tags: swift, extended-ascii

I insert few symbols in my application, some of these symbols appears properly, but some of them only a square with a face appears instead,
Do I need to add any framework in order to display all these symbols properly?
[image]

Comment: Can you show the symbols that you are using(a screenshot will help).

Comment: It is the  and  which cannot be shown:
       case 6:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "A"
        case 7:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "A"

Comment: Please post your actual code, not purely a screenshot to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift, If you want to display any Unicode character use this format :

```
var str="\u{ /*Unicode value*/ }"
```

In your case:

```
cell.textLabel?.text="A\u{FB06}" //A Code for 'st' is FB06
```

***Edit***: Screenshot-
[image]

***Edit 2*** UITableView don't support extended characters. See the comment below.

Comment: Using "\u{FB06}" gave error (required 1 and the beginning i believe), soI used instead the unicode of  which is "\u{1D460}", but still not working.

Comment: No, I am using the latest version of x-code: Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a), i tried random unicode "\u{D55C}" and it work very fine, can you kindly advise if \u{1D460} is the proper unicode of ?

Comment: Well it should work according to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html). If it's not working try this : `"\()"`

Comment: Appreciate your help, using "\()" gave error: used of unresolved identifier 

Comment: I am not sure why it ain't working. it worked for me. I have uploaded a screenshot in the edit.

Comment: it works on background and s appear very fine, but on tableview, it still not showing, i attached a screenshot in edit too

Comment: Please do not put meta commentary (like begging for upvotes and accept votes) in the answer.  Moreover, answers should never have commentary such as "See the comment below".  Please clean up this answer so the comments can be cleaned up.

Comment: I am sorry, that was immature, and I regret doing it @nhgrif. I don't do this now, and I'll change it ASAP.